# Selenium code that works in python/spyder does not works in colab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I am using selenium in Python and Colab.
I have some code that works in spyder, extracts elements but gives me error in collab

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

What is a possible explanation and is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: Before, trying to interact with the element put a time.sleep(certain_time). This will give the element time to load. Though this is not the best practice so take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable

Comment: But this gives me another error:

Comment: An that error is?

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='style__CategoryItem-sc-8ncu0g-2 tZtCz']//span[text()='%s']" %(aaa[1])))).click()`      `TimeoutException: Message: `

Answer (score 1):

Try using this method of waiting before an element Is accessed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path')            
waitshort = WebDriverWait(driver,.5)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
waitLonger = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
visible = EC.visibility_of_element_located        
driver.get('website')
element = wait.until(visible((By.XPATH,'element_xpath'))).click()
```

Comment: still the same error: `TimeoutException: Message:` even I tried all of the waiting options

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thanks for putting your time into providing this answer! Solved my problem of sequencing in a Javascript application within a Spyder IDE.